# Django serve static files e.g. favicon.ico without `{% load static %}`

Tags: django

I have successfully followed the popular solution for serving static files in Django:

- I have `/myproject/myapp/static/favicon.ico`
- I use `<link rel="icon" href="{%static 'favicon.ico' %}" />` in my html template

But if I omit the `<link rel...>` from html then the browser will by default try to GET `/favicon.ico` which predictably logs

```
Not Found: /favicon.ico
```

How can I tell Django "if anything in `urlpatterns` does *not* match the GET string, and that GET string matches a file within a certain directory, just serve that file"?

(Then I would be able to write e.g. `<script src="/script.js">` and have `/myproject/myapp/static-or-wherever/script.js` be served without using `{% use static %}` in a template  -- e.g. if I browse to `http://my-site.com/script.js` manually.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a catch-all URL pattern that matches anything not previously matched and tries to serve the content from the static files directory.

Something along these lines can do:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        'show_indexes': False # to avoid listing directories
    }),
    # ...
    # your other patterns
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that `STATIC_ROOT` was not defined in my case, so I used `settings.BASE_DIR / "myapp/static"`